# Why are there different system enttites for different languages in DialogFlow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

From the screenshots below, we see that @sys.number-integer is not a system entity for French. Why this inconsistency?

English:
[image: English has @sys.number-integer]

French:
[image: French doesn't have @sys.number-integer]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have different intents for different languages, so it's not as if you could use the same entity in the same intent to cover multiple languages anyways. If you're interested in checking out Dialogflow's multi-language agent, you can view that [here](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-multi-locale-nodejs).